I am trying to write a trigger on opportunity that will create order and order item on opportunity update event but facing issue
here is the senerio" when an Opportunity is closed as "Won", the trigger should automatically create a new Order and populate it with Order Line items based on the products and quantities listed on the Opportunity Line items".
trigger CreateOrderOnOpportunityWon on Opportunity (after update) {
    List<Order> ordersToInsert = new List<Order>();
    
    Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>> opportunityLineItemsMap = new Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>>();

    Set<Id> opportunityIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        if (Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName != 'Closed Won' && opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
            opportunityIds.add(opp.Id);
        }
    }
    
    if (!opportunityIds.isEmpty()) {
        List<OpportunityLineItem> opportunityLineItems = [SELECT Id, OpportunityId, Product2Id, Quantity FROM OpportunityLineItem  WHERE OpportunityId IN :opportunityIds];

        for (OpportunityLineItem oli : opportunityLineItems) {
            if (!opportunityLineItemsMap.containsKey(oli.OpportunityId)) {
                opportunityLineItemsMap.put(oli.OpportunityId, new List<OpportunityLineItem>());
            }
            opportunityLineItemsMap.get(oli.OpportunityId).add(oli);
        }

        for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, AccountId, ContractId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :opportunityIds]) {
            Order newOrder = new Order();
            newOrder.AccountId = opp.AccountId;
            newOrder.ContractId = opp.ContractId;
            newOrder.EffectiveDate = Date.today();
            newOrder.Status = 'Draft'; 
            
            ordersToInsert.add(newOrder);
            
            if (opportunityLineItemsMap.containsKey(opp.Id)) {
                for (OpportunityLineItem oli : opportunityLineItemsMap.get(opp.Id)) {
                    OrderItem newOrderItem = new OrderItem();
                    newOrderItem.OrderId = newOrder.Id;  
                    newOrderItem.Product2Id = oli.Product2Id;
                    newOrderItem.Quantity = oli.Quantity;
                    newOrderItem.UnitPrice = oli.UnitPrice;
                    
                    newOrder.OrderItems.add(newOrderItem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (!ordersToInsert.isEmpty()) {
        insert ordersToInsert;
    }
}


What, specifically, is the issue you're facing? If you're getting an error message, then you should copy and paste it verbatim. You can add information to your question by making an [edit].

Your problem lies here
for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, AccountId, ContractId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :opportunityIds]) {
  Order newOrder = new Order();
  newOrder.AccountId = opp.AccountId;
  newOrder.ContractId = opp.ContractId;
  newOrder.EffectiveDate = Date.today();
  newOrder.Status = 'Draft'; 
        
  ordersToInsert.add(newOrder);
        
  if (opportunityLineItemsMap.containsKey(opp.Id)) {
     for (OpportunityLineItem oli : opportunityLineItemsMap.get(opp.Id)) {
        OrderItem newOrderItem = new OrderItem();
        newOrderItem.OrderId = newOrder.Id;  // <== the problem line
        newOrderItem.Product2Id = oli.Product2Id;
        newOrderItem.Quantity = oli.Quantity;
        newOrderItem.UnitPrice = oli.UnitPrice;
                
        newOrder.OrderItems.add(newOrderItem);
            }
        }
    }

On the line newOrderItem.OrderId = newOrder.Id;, you are setting the lookup field on OrderItem to Order. But that Id field doesn't have a value until the insert ordersToInsert; executes!
You'll need to insert the Orders first, create a cross-reference between oportunityId and orderId, then loop through the OpportunityLineItems to built the OrderItems

Shameless plug for the UnitOfWork pattern
With unitofWork, the basic logic of your code changes to (only 6 statements)
trigger CreateOrderOnOpportunityWon on Opportunity (after update) {

    // Application class defines sequence of which sobjectType insertion order
    fflib_ISobjectUnitOfWork = Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance();
    for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, AccountId, ContractId, Pricebook2Id,
                              (SELECT PricebookEntryId, Quantity
                                FROM OpportunityLineItems)
                              FROM Opportunity 
                              WHERE Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]) {
        if (opp.isWon && !Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).IsWon) {
                    
             Order order = new Order(
                AccountId = opp.AccountId,
                ContractId = opp.ContractId,
                Pricebook2Id = opp.Pricebook2Id,
                EffectiveDate = Date.today(),
                Status = 'Draft');
            uow.registerNew(order); 
        
            for (OpportunityLineItem oli : opp.OpportunityLineItems {
                uow.registerNew(new OrderItem(
                   PricebookEntryId =  = oli.PricebookEntryId,
                   Quantity = oli.Quantity,
                   UnitPrice = oli.UnitPrice
                   ),
                   OrderItem.OrderId, // <== relationship field
                   order);            // <== related sobject
            }
        }
    }


    uow.commitWork(); // DML done here in unitOfWork object
} 

